# Picture taken from camera or gallery when using in imageview its orientation getting changed, and sometimes vertically stretched in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, android-gallery

In my application I have to capture image from camera or import from gallery, show it in imageview in activity. Everything is fine, I am getting image from both and able to set it on imageview without any exception. But sometimes image is not getting scaled properly and gets vertically stretched or with orientation changed. Please help me out.

Here is my code to decode image referred from official android documentation:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(File photoFile, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    try {
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(photoFile), null,
                options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(photoFile),
                null, options);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The images has different orientations so it rotates according to the orientation when putting on imageview. You can check the orientation of the photo from properties of image.
To set the image in proper manner you can use the following code...

```
     int rot=getCameraPhotoOrientation(this,Uri,picturePath);
         if(rot!=0)
         bitmap=new RotateOrientation().RotateOrientationCall(bitmap,rot);
```

The **getCameraPhotoOrientation** Method:-

```
 public static int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri, String imagePath){
     int rotate = 0;
     try {
         context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
         File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
         ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                 imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
         int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                 ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                 ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

         switch (orientation) {
         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
             rotate = 270;
             break;
         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
             rotate = 180;
             break;
         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
             rotate = 90;
             break;
         }


         Log.d(TAG, "Exit orientation: " + orientation);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return rotate;
 }
```

Add **RotateOrientation** class to rotate class according to orientation.

```
 public class RotateOrientation  {

Bitmap RotateOrientationCall(Bitmap src,float degree)
        {


        Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degree);
       Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
      return bmOut;

      }
          }
```

Comment: I'll try it and let you know...@Abhishek

Comment: Thanks abhishek, it works fine..I've tested your code in my app.